# Зачем нужны транзакции при чтении БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, spring, transaction

Иногда встречается код, где при чтении информации из БД используется транзакционность (например, аннотация @Transactional), при этом без выставления свойства readOnly = true.

Для чего может понадобится транзакция, если изменения данных или их блокировки только на чтение не происходит и при этом достаётся только один объект или тип объектов?

Comment: Это нужно для обеспечения целостности набора данных, гарантии,  что изменения, вносимые другими программами, не  будет видны при исполнении данного запроса.